# how to show $\lim_{x\to 0}e^x=1$ using $\varepsilon - \delta$

Tags: calculus

Trying to show that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^x=1$$ using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, but am stumped.
$$|f(x)-L|=|e^x-1|=?$$
I got nothing from here...

Comment: What's your definition on $e^x$?

Comment: $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$

Comment: Great. That is continuous everywhere by uniform convergence over any closed interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that since $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k/k!$ by your definition, you have that $|e^{x} - 1| < \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x^k| = |x|/(1-|x|)$ for $|x| < 1$.